# Generating relations of an admissible ideal are not uniquely determined

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

Let $Q=(Q_0,Q_1)$ be a quiver as shown below, where $Q_0=\{1,2\}$, and $Q_1=\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}$, $\alpha:1\to 1$, $\beta:1\to 2$, $\gamma:2\to 1$. I would like to show that two admissible ideals $\mathcal I_1=\langle \alpha^2-\beta\gamma,\gamma\beta-\gamma\alpha\beta,\alpha^4\rangle$ and $\mathcal I_2=\langle \alpha^2-\beta\gamma,\gamma\beta,\alpha^4\rangle$ of $KQ$ induce the same bound quiver algebra, i.e. $KQ/\mathcal I_1\cong KQ/\mathcal I_2$, where $K$ is a field with characteristic different from $2$. Still, $\mathcal I_1\neq \mathcal I_2$.

[image: Quiver]

---

I have shown that $R_Q^4\subseteq \mathcal I_1,\mathcal I_2\subseteq R_Q^2$, so they are admissible, and it is clear that $\gamma\beta\notin \mathcal I_1$, so $\mathcal I_1\neq \mathcal I_2$. However, I am stuck now in determining the path algebra $KQ$, because there are loops and cycles in $Q$. I know that $KQ/\mathcal I$ is a basic and connected finite-dimensional $K$-algebra with an identity, having $R_Q/\mathcal I$ as radical and $\{\epsilon_1+\mathcal I,\epsilon_2+\mathcal I\}$ as a complete set of primitive orthogonal idempotents, for any admissible $\mathcal I$, since $Q$ is a finite connected quiver.

I am also wondering whether there is another way of showing the two bound quiver algebras are isomorphic, without figuring out $KQ$ itself.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I don't know how to do this particular problem but I have got something similiar. First the idea: Give an injective map from $KQ$ to $KQ$ which sends $I_1$ to $I_2$, then we can show that quotients are isomorphic by some isomorphism theorems. We basically do this on the level of generators. There aren't too many choices, because for any set of paths between two particular points we must send them to an invertible linear combination of those same paths. Example below

Comment: Consider a Quiver on 3 vertices $Q_0 = {1, 2, 3}$ two arrows from 1 to 2 named $\alpha, 
 \beta$ and one from 2 to  named $\gamma$.. We  show that quotienting by $I_1 = <\alpha \gamma>$ or $I_2 = <\alpha \gamma - \beta \gamma>$ gives the same result.  You can see the 'change' is $\alpha \to \alpha - \beta$.         So the isomorphism to consider is via $e_1 \to e_1$, $e_2 \to e_2$, $\alpha \to \alpha - \beta$, $\beta \to \beta$ and $\gamma \to \gamma$.

Comment: This gives $KQ / I_1 \cong KQ/I_2$

Comment: For your problem we get it is natural to do $\beta \to \beta - \alpha \beta $ and not change the rest of the generators. This gives $I_2 \to <\alpha^2 - \beta \alpha - \alpha \beta \gamma>= I_3$ which is not exactly what you want